# New Div - "Hiding questions because of your Ignored Tags preferences for tags"

Tags: bug, status-completed, ignored-tags

I think this message/div/box was just added today since I've never noticed it before, it is very noticeable.

[image]

I'm already aware that I'm hiding questions because I selected to hide them in my preferences. Isn't this a bit redundant? Now I have to scroll down more to be able to click to the next page. Plus see that same message dozens upon dozens of times a day.

---

Here are my ignored tags. So I'm going to have to see the same message on any question page that I'm on. Even though I already know questions are being hidden. I'm not understanding the point to this new div/box notification.

Does anyone find this new div/box useful? Do you find it redundant?

[image]

---

EDIT:

Also, this isn't just for StackOverflow.

I only have 2 ignored tags for CodeReview currently. And I have it set for only 15 questions per page. But still, on every page I click to it shows!

[image]

Comment: You don't like a lot of things, do you?

Comment: I just found it very humorous to see how many items you have on your ignore list. I can see why that box would be an issue for you.

Comment: This might be a little more useful if it contained a "display again with filtered results included" link (similar to Google search). Otherwise, it's only really useful to those who've forgotten they've ignored tags.

Comment: I actually don't have ignored tags at the moment, so you might need to refresh my memory... were questions with ignore tags hidden completely or just grayed out?  Is it possible that this UI change now completely hides these questions so you don't have to see them at all.

Comment: @AlienArrays so the preference to hide is part of the change that brought that box.  Would you rather have your list of ignored tags cluttering up your sidebar?

Comment: We're going to change this to something a little less prominent in styling. Should be in the next rollout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly,  I would say just scratch the new div all together because it seems the only useful purpose of this is if I have forgotten I've hidden a tag and want to see that tag for some reason. The problem with that though, is I'm not likely to learn a new programming language or something and forget to remove the tag from my ignored tag lists.

It's kind of like on Windows Systems, popping up a notification that something was just unplugged from your audio jack. Actually, it's more like if Windows popped up a notification every 10 minutes letting you know that you still have something plugged into your audio jack, or you do not have anything plugged in.

As a moderator answered, that they couldn't think of any useful purpose to have the ignore tags in the right sidebar. So I'm not sure how that means move them to the question container is a better place for them.

---

However, if you keep it, I would suggest using something like one of the following styles.

I used background: none for all of them. Since the background should not resemble the background of questions that are in your favorite tags. Also this shouldn't be a feature that stands out so noticeably, since they are ignored tags for a reason.

In order of best to worst in my opinion:

**1)** italic font, text aligned right, opacity .6, smaller font-size, no tag icons

[image]

---

**2)** smaller top/bottom margin spacing, opacity .5, text and tags on same line

[image]

---

**3)** smaller font, less top/bottom margin, no tag icons

[image]

---

**4)** just put the text and tags on the same line

[image]

---

EDIT: A really different approach. Which would be useful if you plan on adding more ignore tags or other stuff in the box would be sliding the ignore footer below the page links like so:

[image]

Comment: I like the smaller designs, I do think there should be an indicator somewhere though

Comment: Thanks for the criticism and suggestions. We're going to go with something similar to your #3

Answer (score 5):

This is all part of the ongoing process to simplify the right sidebar and remove things that aren't useful.

- We've discovered that people use their favorite tags as shortcuts to the tag pages, but we haven't been able to come up with a need for the ignored tags to be in the right sidebar
- I also personally dislike the "gray out ignored tags questions" feature, and I think that if we had to do it over again we would just hide them completely.
- IF we hide them completely, then it was suggested that [some people would forget](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217792/cant-see-my-ignored-tags-anymore-unless-editing-favorite-tags) which tags they hid, so we would need some indication in the list that questions were hidden because of your ignored tags

Here are the changes:

- Ignored tags are no longer displayed in the sidebar by default, but you can see them if you hit edit next to favorite tags
- We have clarified the two options for ignored tags on the preferences page, and changed the default to be "hide ignored tags questions"
- If you have chosen to hide them completely, you will get this new box at the bottom of your results notifying you that some things have been hidden. If you simply gray out the questions, then you will not get the box

I agree for people with lots of ignored tags, this could be annoying.  I'm considering either making it dismissible (but I think you are likely to forget sometime down the line), make it smaller/less noticeable, or only display when we've hidden more than X amount of questions (although this would not fix your specific problem).

Open to other suggestions or opinions.

Comment: Fair enough, but you must admit that "you can see them if you hit edit next to favorite tags" isn't the best experience. It's like "you can add comment if you favorite the question", as the action of *editing favorite tags* having a side effect of showing your ignored tags is highly unexpected and impossible to guess. Hope you see my point?

Comment: I most definitely use my favourite tags as a shortcut and never use the ignored tags at all (so thank you for de-cluttering!). However, it's not obvious that you can edit the ignored tags by clicking edit next to the favourites. If you could see your way to making this more obvious you'll probably confuse less people.

Comment: You are both correct. It's not great UX, but the primary path to edit ignored tags really should be the link in the notice.  I thought about removing ignored tags completely even when you click edit, but I figured there's no harm done for leaving them for users who are used to finding them there.

Comment: @JeremyTunnell while I don't agree with this entire feature request, I think the OP brings up a good point in the [comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217664/new-div-hiding-questions-because-of-your-ignored-tags-preferences-for-tags#comment705673_217664).  Making the background the same as a favorite tag is somewhat odd, and it may be worth considering a change.

Comment: What about an option to show hidden questions in the footer. I mean the questions are there, but not displayed. Currently it looks a little weird, if you are one the first page with a page Size of 15, but only 2 questions are displayed.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Good suggestion,we're going to go with something more like #3 below