# Can't see my ignored tags anymore unless editing favorite tags

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, ignored-tags, homepage

On Stack Overflow, I got bunch of favorite tags and couple of ignored tags. Both groups used to show in the front page, until today:

> [image]

When editing the favorite tags they do appear though so not all is lost:

> [image]

Can I see my ignored tags without having to edit?

Comment: Why would you need to see a list of your ignored tags?

Comment: @JeremyTunnell suppose I marked a tag as ignored three years ago. I totally forgot about it, and now wonder why I can't see questions with that tag in the front page. Now that we don't see ignored tags anymore, 99% of the people will assume it means "you don't have any ignored tags". In my opinion if you go this way better hide it all and have a link "Manage favorite and ignored tags" that will open both groups.

Comment: See here for the other side of the discussion http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217664/new-div-hiding-questions-because-of-your-ignored-tags-preferences-for-tags

Comment: @JeremyTunnell I can't reproduce, don't see the "Hiding questions because of..." message even though adding ignored tags of questions that were in the list. Those questions just disappear after refresh, without any explanation. If such thing will work I agree it's suitable alternative to showing ignored tags.

Comment: It's not displayed if you're just graying questions out. Would you prefer that you see that notice?

Comment: @JeremyTunnell yes, the "gray out" option does not apply in the front page aka Interesting Questions list (it won't show questions with tags I ignore because they're probably not something I find interesting, which makes sense) so better show the box anyway, at least in Stack Overflow homepage.